# Pass value from input in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, return-value, repeater

I have a repeater to list products. Users enter amount and aprrove it.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptItems_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input name="Amount" id="Amount" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" type="number" step=".01" max="<%#Eval("AMOUNT") %>" min="0.01" placeholder="Enter amount (Max: <%#Eval("AMOUNT") %> <%#Eval("UNIT") %>)" style="width:100%; padding:10px 5px 10px 0; font-size:12px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center;" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="bt" runat="server" Text="ADD TO BASKET" Width="100%" CommandName="ButtonClick" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

```
protected void rptItems_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "ButtonClick")
    {

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        string SQLOrdD = "INSERT INTO N_ORDERDETAIL (ClientID, ProductID, Amount) VALUES (@ClientID, @ProductID, @Amount);
        SqlCommand rsOrdD = new SqlCommand(SQLOrdD, bag.Bagla());


        decimal Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form["Amount"]);



        rsOrdD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientID", Session["ClientID"]);
        rsOrdD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", PrID);
        rsOrdD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", Amount);

        bag.Bagla().Close();
    }
}
```

How can I get the value of the amount.
Thanks...

Comment: Is that `Request.Form["Amount"]` returns null value? Are you getting any errors or `Amount` simply filled with zero? Please explain further details to identify the problem origins.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Yes.It turns null. I'm not getting any error.

Comment: Try examine `Request.Form.AllKeys` in debugger, is that your `Request.Form` actually has a key named `Amount`? If not, I suggest you using `asp:TextBox` server control, find its control ID from `RepeaterItem` & get the value from it. Also are you binding the repeater data in `Page_Load` event?

Comment: Repeater works fine. But my repeater data in a method because I am using a pager. I call repeater every page click.

Comment: Which event method manages repeater data binding? If `Request.Form.AllKeys` doesn't contain a key named `Amount`, probably the repeater repopulated before submit event fires so that the request key was lost, and you need to check against postback before binding.

Comment: Request.Form.AllKeys contains a key named `Amount` but it is null. I manage repeater protected void GetItems() method

Comment: Can I get values this way: `Amount = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("Amount")).Text` etc